# Pro Mini Broken PWM Output

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, motor, pwm, signal

I am trying to ride a 9g servo with a 3.3V 8MHz arduino pro mini. The servo moves between 0 and 90 degrees so ı decided to investigate. I hooked the set up to an oscilloscope and saw that the pro mini outputs 0.2ms pulses at servo.write(0), and 1ms pulses at servo.write(180). I tried using servo.attach(pin, 500, 2000) and servo.writeMiliseconds but nothing worked.

Comment: Why do they say "minimum (0-degree) angle on the servo (defaults to 544)

max (optional): the pulse width, in microseconds, corresponding to the maximum (180-degree) angle on the servo (defaults to 2400)"

Comment: But I can move the same servo with an arduino nano which can supply a 2ms pulse. Plus, I cant make my pro mini to give more than 1ms, doesnt matter if servo is suitable or not at this point.

Comment: insufficient info to diagnose your problem

Answer (score 0):

The arduino library command is https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/servo/writemicroseconds/

servo.writeMicroseconds(us) not milliseconds.

Comment: Yes its my bad, I use microseconds.